# How can I configure Adobe Help so it doesn't chatter so much with Adobe's domain?

Tags: macos, spyware, adobe-cs5

Adobe Help that came with Creative Suite 5 and/or Flash Builder Pro is constantly creating network traffic with an Adobe site, www.wip4.adobe.com

In the Adobe Help application Preferences, I find that I can change the settings so that I must manually download updates, but apparently the application still likes to call home and chatter non-stop with www.wip4.adobe.com.  I could use something like Little Snitch to block all this spyware-like behavior, but I'd really prefer to just change the application's behavior.  Is there a hidden setting or configuration file to adjust this behavior to something more appropriate and polite?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called your hosts file in `/etc/hosts`. Simply create an entry pointing `www.wip4.adobe.com` to `127.0.0.1`.

This **will** stop the chatter, but it's not exactly a "hidden setting" in the application itself. To the best of my knowledge Adobe is about as invasive as Google, except you pay through the nose for the privilege.